# Angularjs Multiple select box on each row

Tags: angularjs

I am creating the row dynamically with multiple select box as one of the form field in Angularjs 1.7.5.

Each row has two Multiple select box [Input & Selected]

View:

```
  <select name="inoutvaluedy" class="custom-select" multiple ng-model="available" ng-options="client as client for client in availableclients"></select>
<button id="moveright" class="btn_arrow_style" type="button" value="Add Client" ng-click="additem(available)"></button>
<button id="moveleft" class="btn_arrow_style" type="button" value="Remove Client" ng-click="removeitem(input)"></button>
<select name="selectedclients"  class="custom-select" multiple ng-model="input" ng-options="client as client for client in selectedclients"></select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.availableclients = ["fromEmail", "toEmail", "Content"];
$scope.selectedclients = [];
$scope.columns = [{id: 1, input:$scope.selectedclients}];
 $scope.addNewColumn = function() {
var newItemNo = $scope.columns.length + 1;
$scope.columns.push({
  id: newItemNo,
  input: $scope.selectedclients
});  };
//Add item to selected
$scope.additem = function(items) {
items.forEach(function(item) {
  $scope.selectedclients.push(item);
  $scope.availableclients.splice(items, 1);
});}
//Remove item from selected
$scope.removeitem = function(items) {
items.forEach(function(item) {
  $scope.selectedclients.push(item);
  $scope.availableclients.splice(item, 1);
});}
```

Issue:
When adding row. The multiple Select box repeated with same item.I need to have a unique selected item on each row.

May be my approach would be wrong. Please take a look on my plunker and correct me. Thanks in Advance

https://embed.plnkr.co/fVEc4xljSQvOVz4zDeUM/

Comment: you have more than just the issue you describe here.  Your code to move items from one list to another is broken, and if you were to fix the code to show multiple list groups, those buttons wouldn't even know which list group to target.  Also, you should provide a [mcve] in the question body;  plunker links aren't a replacement for actual code in the question.

Comment: my suggestion would be to consider making a directive to encapsulate all the logic and UI, and then have your `add task` button add new copies of the directive.

Comment: Thanks @claies. I'm new to Angularjs .I tried all my way to fix this. Could you provide any links with example where I could refer.

Comment: I would rewrite quite a bit of this code, to be honest.  Start with learning how to create View Models instead of using the `$scope` directly.  From there, it will be much easier to create a directive which works for a single group of lists, and then make the directive repeatable.  I would say that most of these topics would be covered in the **excellent** [AngularJs Style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#table-of-contents) by John Papa.